# Tile overlapping existing toilet flange - flange extenders don't fit

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, tile, toilet

I'm replacing the toilet in the master bedroom. I pulled the old toilet off to discover the toilet flange is about 5/8" below the tile floor. I went to the store and got toilet flange extenders (the kind where you put silicone between each one) only to discover that the tile wasn't actually cut all the way around the flange so the spacer doesn't fit.

[image]
[image]

What are my options here? Is there a way to remedy this without cutting the tile? The old toilet did not seem to have any kind of flange extender.

EDIT: I just realized one of these is in there: https://www.fernco.com/plumbing/wax-free-toilet-seal

Seems like that might do what I want. Any opinions?

Answer (score 2):

This is honestly a 30 second job with an angle grinder (plus diamond wheel).   Wet area (rewet wheel and area if this takes any significant time), make sure grinder is pretty close to 90 degrees, if worried about hitting something under then just go halfway and chip out.   Your cuts don't have to be great as they will be covered by toilet.   Would also suggest taping the area you are cutting.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used one of the wax free seal extenders you linked but you can get extra thick wax seals, which is probably what was there before, and repair rings for the flange (looks bad from the picture).  The repair rings don't actually replace the flange but sit on top and you screw them down into the subfloor. They come in very handy when replacing the flange isn't an option.

Google `toilet flange replacement'` and `extra thick wax ring` to get more info.

EDIT: After looking closer at your pictures, the flange goes directly into an elbow. If you get the wax-free seal, make sure that it won't extend below the elbow and partially block the flow of waste. Not sure if the seal is trimable or not.

Two repair rings. There are others as well
[image]
[image]